# Why do I get a syntax error when I'm trying to restart Apache?

Tags: php, apache

httpd: Syntax error on line 69 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: Cannot load lib/httpd/modules/mod_authn_file.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/httpd/lib/httpd/modules/mod_authn_file.so, 10): image not found

Comment: Does your system contain a file `/usr/local/opt/httpd/lib/httpd/modules/mod_authn_file.so` ?

Comment: httpd: Syntax error on line 67 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: Cannot load lib/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/httpd/lib/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so, 10): image not found.. im getting also this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Apache configuration in **httpd.conf**, line 69 tries to use authn_file mod, which should be defined in the **mod_authn_file.so** at the location of

> **/usr/local/opt/httpd/lib/httpd/modules/mod_authn_file.so**

You will need to ensure that

- the path is correct
- the file is there
- the file is not corrupted
- the user running the webserver has access to that path

or, if you do not need that mod, then you can switch it off.

Comment: I have similar problems. Can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65141476/why-are-there-some-warnings-when-cross-compiling-apache-httpd-2-4-46

Comment: Downvoted. This is not a solution. If the path is incorrect, or the file isn't there, as mine isn't? What then? I've been clicking my heels furiously and shouting "/usr/local/opt/httpd/lib/httpd/modules/mod_authn_file.so APPEAR! /usr/local/opt/httpd/lib/httpd/modules/mod_authn_file.so APPEAR!" but that hasn't helped, so obviously there is some other step required.

Comment: @JohnSmith if you reread the question then you will see the specific path you object against is actually part of the error message the question's problem revolved around. You might have different settings, but the problem of the asker was that the file specified at this specific location was unreachable at the time of asking.